# How should I add hiredis to my package.json file?

Tags: node.js, redis, npm

I see that installing [hiredis](https://github.com/pietern/hiredis-node/) requires a format I've not seen before.  Instead of the expected:

```
npm install hiredis
```

...the format is actually:

```
npm install hiredis redis
```

How should I go about adding hiredis to my package.json dependencies so that it installs properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `redis` module will automatically use `hiredis` if it's available.

```
npm install redis hiredis
```

is identical to

```
npm install redis
npm install hiredis
```

In short, just include it in your `package.json` like any other module.

```
"dependencies": {
  "redis": "",
  "hiredis": ""
}
```

Comment: Ahh, alright.  I was unfamiliar with the fact that `npm install` could accept multiple packages, and assumed that it was aliasing `redis` to `hiredis` (or something like that).  Thanks!